# How to test a function that uses setTimeout() internally with mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Consider the below function,

```
function helloAfter100ms(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('hello');
  },100)
}
```

Test code with mocha,

```
describe('#helloAfter100ms()',function(){
  it('console logs hello ONLY after 100ms',function(){
    // what should go here
  })
})
```

Comment: I suggest you to use also `sinon` with mocha, which offers you ways for spying/mocking stuff and times manipulation for these cases of `timeout` for example: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Spies

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're trying to test something that you shouldn't. The name of your test suggests you don't trust that the `setTimeout` function calls the `console.log` only after the given timeout.

Since this is not your code, you should probably not unit test it. Furthermore, `setTimeout` is probable something you can be sure works properly.

So what's left to test? Your code - the code that *calls* `setTimeout`.
You can make sure that you're calling setTimeout correctly.

As to how this is done - there are two sinon features you can use. The first is `useFakeTimers` which gives you control of the clock. The second is a spy, which you should use on the `console.log` to make sure it was called.

```
describe('#helloAfter100ms()',function(){
  it('console logs hello ONLY after 100ms',function(){
    const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    helloAfter100ms();
    expect(logSpy).to.not.have.been.called;
    clock.tick(100);
    expect(logSpy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    logSpy.restore();
    clock.restore();
  }
}
```

Comment: @chris sharp I'm not sure what you mean, but you should probably ask a new question instead of commenting on old answers.

Comment: @ChrisSharp please [don't ask questions in answer comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321819/can-comment-contain-a-question). Also, it would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete, verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

**Updated: like this:**

```
describe('helloAfter100ms', function(){
   it('console logs hello ONLY after 100ms', function(done){
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log('hello.');
           done();
       }, 100)
   })
})
```

**Reference: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code**

Comment: this is not a test if you call again the `console.log` you have instead to create a spy on it and check that it has been called with the right parameter

Comment: @quirimmo Updated !!

Comment: sorry for being picky, the concept of async through calling the `done` is totally perfect. But if you want to test if after 3 seconds a `console.log` has been called, you need to create a spy on the method and to check that the method has been called with the right parameter. This doesn't mean to call the `console.log` again. 
But again, the logic of` `done` is totally perfect.

Comment: `this.timeout(100);`  timeouts may also be applied, or the use of `this.timeout(0);` to disable timeouts all together

Comment: Copying the implementation of a function into the test makes the test very brittle. Also, it doesn't test the required function - `helloAfter100ms`. What happens when that function changes? The test will keep passing.

Comment: Not sure we should really wait it over. This solution will definitely not suffice for greater timeouts.